# Print out an array in objective-c

Tags: java, ios, objective-c

I have a problem about printing an array. 
I am a java user, and i am new to objective-c.

in java code, i show u what i want

```
 for(myClass a: myVariable){
     System.out.println(a.toString);
 }
```

so how do i do this in objective-c, i have written like this:

```
- (void) updateTextField:(NSMutableArray *)array{
    for (Storage *obj in array)   // Storage class holds a name and a price.
        [check setText:@"%@",[obj description]];  // i did override the description method to print out the name and price.  and "Check" is my textField; 
}
```

it does not work. [check setText:@"%@",obj description]; got error "too many argument to method call if i take out the description;"

here is my Storage.m
   #import "Storage.h"

```
@implementation Storage


@synthesize name;
@synthesize price;

- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@        %@", name, price];
}

@end
```

Comment: You should say either `obj.description` or `[obj description]`.  The use of `[]` for method calls is very disorienting when coming from Java.

Comment: hey guys, i did try this [check setText:@"%@",[obj description]]; but it still show me an error " too many argument to method call, expected 1 but 2;"

Comment: You can't simply use `@"%@"` and get something formatted.  It needs to be something like `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[obj description]]`.  (You were the one who wanted to switch from Java.)

Comment: Note that the `description` method shouldn't be used in production code.  Great for debugging/logging/learning, though.

Comment: (Or, for a full statement, `[check setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[obj description]]];`)

Comment: @bblum - With one exception -- can you name it?

Comment: thanks @HotLicks , no more error now.  thanks guys for taking ur time to help me

Comment: Re: bbum's comment; you'd normally use `stringValue` if you have, say, an array of `NSNumber`s and want a defined, deterministic-across-verions way of outputting strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your commented error on Ryan's post you could try this:

```
- (void) updateTextField:(NSMutableArray *)array{
    for (Storage *obj in array)
        [check setText:[NSString stringWithString:obj.description]];
}
```

Comment: @user1933421 In strict Cocoa terms, that should be a lot of wasted processing — `setText:` implies you're setting a property so if your array is 1000 elements long then setting the value you don't want 999 times and then the actual value is a waste. If `check` is appending, you might consider a more compact form without the explicit loop like `[[obj valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@","]`

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax for what you did would be `[check setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [obj description]]];`.  But you can just use `NSLog` in a similar manner as Java's sysout:

```
for(Storage *obj in array)
    NSLog(@"%@", obj); //the description will be called implicitly, like toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Does `-setText:` take a format list or just an `NSString`?

That is, try:

```
- (void) updateTextField:(NSMutableArray *)array{
    for (Storage *obj in array)  
        [check setText:[obj description]];
}
```